# Breaking out of while True in a twisted python example?

Tags: python, twisted

When I do the following:

```
count = 0
while True: 
    count += 1
    try: 
        print count 
    except IOError:
        print 'cannot open'
```

This prints 0, 1, 2, etc.. as expected. But in the following twisted python example, the execution breaks out of while loop even though `print ('bytesread read: ', bytes)` is executed. Is there something I missed?

```
 class PoetrySocket(object):

    poem = ''

    def __init__(self, task_num, address):
        self.task_num = task_num
        self.address = address
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect(address)
        self.sock.setblocking(0)

        # tell the Twisted reactor to monitor this socket for reading
        from twisted.internet import reactor
        reactor.addReader(self)

    def fileno(self):
        try:
            return self.sock.fileno()
        except socket.error:
            return -1

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.sock.close()

        # stop monitoring this socket
        from twisted.internet import reactor
        reactor.removeReader(self)

        # see if there are any poetry sockets left
        for reader in reactor.getReaders():
            if isinstance(reader, PoetrySocket):
                return

        reactor.stop() # no more poetry

    def doRead(self):
        bytes = ''
        count = 0

        while True:
            count += 1
            try:
                bytesread = self.sock.recv(1024)
                if not bytesread:
                    break
                else:
                    bytes += bytesread
                    print ('bytesread read: ', bytes)
            except socket.error, e:pe
                if e.args[0] == errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
                    break
                return main.CONNECTION_LOST

            print ('count read: ', count)

        print ('task? : ', bytes)
        if not bytes:
            print 'Task %d finished' % self.task_num
            return main.CONNECTION_DONE
        else:
            msg = 'Task %d: got %d bytes of poetry from %s'
            print  msg % (self.task_num, len(bytes), self.format_addr())

        self.poem += bytes

    def logPrefix(self):
        return 'poetry'

    def format_addr(self):
        host, port = self.address
        return '%s:%s' % (host or '127.0.0.1', port)


def poetry_main():
    addresses = parse_args()

    start = datetime.datetime.now()

    sockets = [PoetrySocket(i + 1, addr) for i, addr in enumerate(addresses)]

    from twisted.internet import reactor
    reactor.run()

    elapsed = datetime.datetime.now() - start

    for i, sock in enumerate(sockets):
        print 'Task %d: %d bytes of poetry' % (i + 1, len(sock.poem))

    print 'Got %d poems in %s' % (len(addresses), elapsed)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    poetry_main()
```

Print out below:

```
('bytesread read: ', 'The Fascin')
('count read: ', 1)
('task? : ', 'The Fascin')
Task 2: got 10 bytes of poetry from 127.0.0.1:10001
('bytesread read: ', 'The Ecstasy\n\nWhere, like a pil')
('count read: ', 1)
('task? : ', 'The Ecstasy\n\nWhere, like a pil')
Task 1: got 30 bytes of poetry from 127.0.0.1:10000
('bytesread read: ', 'Sonnet - T')
('count read: ', 1)
('task? : ', 'Sonnet - T')
Task 3: got 10 bytes of poetry from 127.0.0.1:10002
('bytesread read: ', 'low on a bed\n         A pregna')
('count read: ', 1)
('task? : ', 'low on a bed\n         A pregna')
Task 1: got 30 bytes of poetry from 127.0.0.1:10000
('bytesread read: ', 'ation of w')
('count read: ', 1)
('task? : ', 'ation of w')
Task 2: got 10 bytes of poetry from 127.0.0.1:10001
('bytesread read: ', 'o Science\n')
('count read: ', 1)
('task? : ', 'o Science\n')
Task 3: got 10 bytes of poetry from 127.0.0.1:10002
('bytesread read: ', "nt bank swell'd up to rest\nThe")
('count read: ', 1)
```

Comment: Is it that the `self.sock.recv()` caused an exception, which caused you to break out of the loop?

Comment: Did you mean to print 'count read' outside of that inner loop?
I think it's probably looping back and exiting on the next loop through, but if you added or moved a print, you'd see that pretty quickly.

Comment: thanks!! there was an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sock.recv()` returns `''` on EOF, so if the remote end of the socket closes the file, it will exit the loop immediately.